# Laptop mini PCI-E wifi module to PCI 2.2 slot

Tags: wireless-networking, pci-express, pci, minipci

I'm thinking of sorta *rebuilding* my first PC I had in 2005 which had a Celeron processor. The [P4i45GV motherboard](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/P4i45GV%20R5.0/) only have three PCI 2.2 slots, an AGP slot and an AMR slot (which I don't know what it is). And I have a wifi module from a broken notebook of a friend of mine and I though of connecting it to that old motherboard.
So, I'm just curious that it is possible and I'm not getting any good search results on 'mini pcie to pci 2.2' though.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

AMR stands for "Audio/Modem Riser" and is designed to hold small cards that have that type of hardware on them.

Not sure if this motherboard has on-board audio that's designed to connected to the front panel of your case.  If it doesn't, you can find and install an AMR card for sound or find and install a PCI sound card.

The reason why you're not finding any adapters is because your adapter is a PCI-*E*, and this board only has plain PCI.  While PCI-E and PCI are software compatible, they are very different on the hardware and connector end.

Mini PCI-E to desktop PCI-E converters exist, but not to plain PCI.

You will need to get an old PCI wifi card or a cheap USB wifi adapter.

Note that at 2GB of RAM maximum this system is going to be problematic for any modern use.

Comment: As I can recall, it had front panel audio by default. And no I'm not going to use it for modern use, of course not! I just leave it with win xp (along with 98 perhaps)